# Writing bytes to text file and reading them appropriately

Tags: c#, byte, text-files, huffman-code

What I have done is I have successfully used the **Huffman Encoding algorithm** to compress text into smaller bytes. For example, **instead of every character being 8 bits, some are 3, 4 or 5** etc. making them compressed, but still being read as the same text by my functions.

My question is, how do I then write these bytes to a text file, but then also decode the bytes with my own custom functions **instead of notepad or other text-file-opening programs reading the data as 8 bits at a time.**

If it helps, here is my implementation of the algorithm. It isn't the best, but it works well:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HuffmanTree huffmanCompression = new HuffmanTree("C:\\Users\\Parv\\Downloads\\OliverTwist.txt");

        string code = huffmanCompression.Encode(); Console.WriteLine("\n" + code);
        string decoded = huffmanCompression.Decode(code); Console.WriteLine("\n" + decoded);
        float percentage = huffmanCompression.OutputCompressionPercentage();
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + percentage.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class CharacterCounter
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> dict;

    public CharacterCounter(string fileDirectory, bool SortTable = false, bool PrintTableToConsole = false)
    {
        dict = ReadTextFile(fileDirectory);
        if (SortTable)
            dict = SortDictionary(dict);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dict)
        {
            if (item.Value == 0)
            {
                dict.Remove(item.Key);
            }
        }

        if (PrintTableToConsole)
            DisplayDictionary(dict);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, int> ReadTextFile(string directory)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(directory);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Dispose(); reader.Close();

        Dictionary<string, int> Counter = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        int LineBreakCount = 0;

        foreach (char character in text)
        {
            switch (character)
            {
                case '\n':
                    LineBreakCount++;
                    break;

                case '\r':
                    LineBreakCount++;
                    break;

                case '\t':
                    if (Counter.ContainsKey("TAB"))
                        Counter["TAB"] += 1;
                    else
                        Counter.Add("TAB", 1);
                    break;

                default:
                    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
                    {
                        if (Counter.ContainsKey("SPACE"))
                            Counter["SPACE"] += 1;
                        else
                            Counter.Add("SPACE", 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Counter.ContainsKey(character.ToString()))
                            Counter[character.ToString()] += 1;
                        else
                            Counter.Add(character.ToString(), 1);
                    }
                    break;
            }       
        }
        Counter.Add("NEWLINE", (int)Math.Round((float)(LineBreakCount / 2)));
        return Counter;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, int> SortDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> charFrequencies)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ListOfChars = charFrequencies.ToList();

        ListOfChars.Sort(delegate (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair1,
                        KeyValuePair<string, int> pair2)
                        {
                            return pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value);
                        });

        return ListOfChars.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    }

    private void DisplayDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> SortedCharFrequencies)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in SortedCharFrequencies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class HuffmanTree
{
    List<Tree> ConnectedTrees = new List<Tree>();
    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
    Dictionary<string, string> LookupTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string Directory = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Huffman Tree using the frequency of characters in a text file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directory"></param>
    public HuffmanTree(string directory)
    {
        Directory = directory;
        CharacterCounter counter = new CharacterCounter(directory, true, true);
        // Populates a dictionary with the frequency of every letter in a file in order
        Console.WriteLine();

        List<Tree> Trees = new List<Tree>();

        string[] characters = counter.dict.Keys.ToArray();
        int[] frequencies = counter.dict.Values.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            Tree Tree = new Tree(characters[i], frequencies[i]);
            Trees.Add(Tree);
        } // Creates a forest of one-member trees for each char in the dictionary

        CreateTwoTrees(Trees); // Creates two new joined trees
        CombineSmallestTrees(Trees); // Combines the two smallest trees -
        // - and repeats till one tree is left

        int MasterNodeValue = Trees[0].Value;
        foreach (Tree item in ConnectedTrees)
        {
            FindCode(item, MasterNodeValue);
            LookupTable.Add(item.Character, Reverse(code.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(item.Character + ", " + code.ToString());
            code.Clear();
        } // Creates lookup table for each tree with a char
    }

    private string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }

    private void CreateTwoTrees(List<Tree> Trees)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i += 2)
        {
            try
            {
                Tree Tree = new Tree(Trees[i], Trees[i + 1])
                {
                    LeftTree = Trees[i],
                    RightTree = Trees[i + 1]
                };
                if (Tree.LeftTree.Character != "default")
                    ConnectedTrees.Add(Tree.LeftTree);
                if (Tree.RightTree.Character != "default")
                    ConnectedTrees.Add(Tree.RightTree);

                Tree.LeftTree.TreeAttachedTo = Tree;
                Tree.LeftTree.AttachedByLeft = true;
                Tree.RightTree.TreeAttachedTo = Tree;
                Tree.RightTree.AttachedByRight = true;

                Trees.Remove(Trees[i + 1]); Trees.Remove(Trees[i]);
                Trees.Add(Tree);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Tree of 1
            }
        }
    }

    private void CombineSmallestTrees(List<Tree> Trees)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Tree Tree = new Tree(Trees[i], Trees[i + 1])
                {
                    LeftTree = Trees[i],
                    RightTree = Trees[i + 1]
                };
                if (Tree.LeftTree.Character != "default")
                    ConnectedTrees.Add(Tree.LeftTree);
                if (Tree.RightTree.Character != "default")
                    ConnectedTrees.Add(Tree.RightTree);

                Tree.LeftTree.TreeAttachedTo = Tree;
                Tree.LeftTree.AttachedByLeft = true;
                Tree.RightTree.TreeAttachedTo = Tree;
                Tree.RightTree.AttachedByRight = true;

                Trees.Remove(Trees[i + 1]); Trees.Remove(Trees[i]);
                Trees.Add(Tree);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Tree of 1
            }
        }

        if (Trees.Count != 1)
        {
            CreateTwoTrees(Trees);
            CombineSmallestTrees(Trees);
        }
    }

    private void FindCode(Tree tree, int max)
    {
        if (tree.Value != max)
        {
            if (tree.AttachedByLeft)
            {
                code.Append("0");
                FindCode(tree.TreeAttachedTo, max);
            }
            else if (tree.AttachedByRight)
            {
                code.Append("1");
                FindCode(tree.TreeAttachedTo, max);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (tree.AttachedByLeft)
                code.Append("0");
            else if (tree.AttachedByRight)
                code.Append("1");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string of bytes which contain the encoded string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Encode()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char item in text)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in LookupTable)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case '\n':
                        if (pair.Key == "NEWLINE")
                            builder.Append(pair.Value);
                        break;
                    case '\t':
                        if (pair.Key == "TAB")
                            builder.Append(pair.Value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(item))
                        {
                            if (pair.Key == "SPACE")
                                builder.Append(pair.Value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pair.Key == item.ToString())
                                builder.Append(pair.Value);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the text deciphered from the encoded string of bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Decode(string bytes)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char item in bytes)
        {
            builder.Append(item);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in LookupTable)
            {
                if (pair.Value == builder.ToString())
                {
                    switch (pair.Key)
                    {
                        case "SPACE":
                            text.Append(" ");
                            break;
                        case "TAB":
                            text.Append("    ");
                            break;
                        case "NEWLINE":
                            text.Append("\n");
                            break;
                        default:
                            text.Append(pair.Key);
                            break;
                    }
                    
                    builder.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        return text.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the percentage change between uncompressed and compressed data
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public float OutputCompressionPercentage()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        float UncompressedBytes = text.Length * 8;
        float CompressedBytes = Encode().Length;

        float Percentage = (CompressedBytes - UncompressedBytes) / UncompressedBytes;
        return Percentage * 100;
    }
}

public class Tree
{
    public int Value;
    public string Character = "default";
    public int Frequency;

    public Tree LeftTree;
    public Tree RightTree;

    public Tree TreeAttachedTo;
    public bool AttachedByRight = false;
    public bool AttachedByLeft = false;

    public Tree(string character, int frequency)
    {
        Character = character;
        Frequency = frequency;
        Value = frequency;
    }

    public Tree(Tree leftTree, Tree rightTree)
    {
        Value = leftTree.Value + rightTree.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not write the huffman-encoded string to a *text file*, but to a *binary file*.

Comment: Please never write multiple statements on one line of code. 1) it makes the code unreadable 2) it makes the code undebuggable in some cases. Make all `;` as last character on the code line.

Comment: Sorry, I only did that for testing purposes. Console.WriteLine() isn't something that needs to be well-readable IMO. Also, writing to a binary file sounds like it would help. Thanks.

Comment: Update: So I tried writing to a binary file using the BinaryWriter class, however, writing bits to a binary file isn't what I had in mind. I always believed that text files were written using bits and those bits make up each char in the file. If I just write all the bits to the binary file, the size of that file is still quite huge (huger than before I compressed it). So is there another step that I need to do to have a compressed text file or do I need to try another approach? Thanks